# Use policy if parameter exists

Tags: wildcard, url-parameters, openam

Using OpenAM: 10.0.1 and having URLs that look like:

```
http://domain/apps/index?Id=00
```

which matches the following policy

```
http://domain/apps/*?*
```

I want to make `http://domain/apps/index?Id=01` use a different policy which follows a specific authentication chaining (HOPT, required).

So I tried creating it and using the exact same URL setting the authentication chaining at the condition but OpenAM ignores it, unless the other policy is disabled.

My conclussion, if the URL matches two policies, either of them can grant access.

Any idea on how to force using a specific policy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which policy mode is configured for the agent, subtree or selfmode?

Comment: The agent is configured on  selfmode